# Webrequest with quotes

Tags: c#, webrequest, xbmc

I want to build a little remote tool for a school project. (XBMC)

At first I would say, that a string variable doesn´t include quotes, but \", which should picture quotes in a textbox and somewhere else. Firstly i mean C# makes quotes with that trick in a Webrequest too, but he doesn´t. Furthermore i can reach my device, but the ResponseReader doesn´t give any answer, but this isn´t important, because i can delete this part in need.

Here is an example for the variable `Übergabe`:

```
{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"Input.Up\"}
```

textBox2.Text includes the password and textBox1.Text includes the server.

---

How should i solve this?

I'm trying to make this WebRequest (method) work:

```
   private void Xorg (string Übergabe)
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest MyRequest;
                MyRequest = WebRequest.Create(("http://root:") + (textBox2.Text) + ("@") + (textBox1.Text) + ("/jsonrpc?request=") + (Übergabe));
                MyRequest.Method = "GET";
                textBox3.Text = ("http://root:*****") + ("@") + (textBox1.Text) + ("/jsonrpc?request=") + (Übergabe);
                Stream ResponseStream;
                ResponseStream = MyRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader ResponseReader = new StreamReader(ResponseStream);

                while (ResponseReader.ReadLine() != null)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(ResponseReader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            catch
            { listBox2.Items.Add("Server antwortet nicht! / Fehlerhafte Eingabe!"); }
       }
```

Comment: You only need to escape characters with a backslash when you're writing code. The actual content of strings does not need to have escaped characters. Also, you don't need to wrap everything in parenthesis `(...)`...

Comment: But I have written the part of the URL, which includes the quotes, in a string variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WebUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx) :

```
WebRequest MyRequest = WebRequest.Create(("http://root:") + (textBox2.Text) + ("@") + (textBox1.Text) + ("/jsonrpc?request=") + WebUtility.UrlEncode(Übergabe));
```

`"` must be converted to `%22`. With UrlEncode you ensure that all character are properly converted

Comment: Hello, the Webutility method doesn´t have this option in my version :( Are there any alternative methods?

Comment: @user3792550, Try with System.Uri.EscapeDataString(Übergabe)

Comment: I now works fine (System.Uri), but I can't reach the URL with the converted string....

Comment: Here is the URL including the converted string: http://root:****@**.****.****.****:***/jsonrpc?request=%7B%22jsonrpc%22%3A%222.0%22%2C%22method%22%3A%22System.Shutdown%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%7D

Comment: @user3792550 Seems good, you may have another issue than encoding. Try to send a raw request with fiddler or typing the url in a browser and check the result.

Comment: Ahh, I know! I doesn't have the authentication for that, but why? Can you explain, why i can't use the authentication like root:password.. Please :) (It work´s in a browser)

Comment: @user3792550, ask another question on SO or search on Google ;) You are looking for Basic Authentication and WebRequest.